# Draw line in google map follow the route

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, line, routes

I would like a same solution like here:

[Sample](http://map.netkvik.dk/0437)

but I didn't find a solution nowhere. The big problem is the follow the route, so I can draw line beetween 2 points, but it's not good. 
What is the solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Directions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/) API.  You can find more information on how to make Directions request in Maps in the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#DirectionsRequests).

[Here](http://dreamdealer.nl/tutorials/getting_directions_with_google_maps.html) is one tutorial on using the API.